# Batch add keys into JSON files in a directory based on condition

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I am looking for a way to batch add keys to all JSON file in a directory preferably with command line tools.

Files:

```
/config$ ls
166bbdd41c0297755ddb645db2b4c865  46a5c83d30483acba49a542a1ade9c33  87b2a640a5398156bf2d924b130ce42c  ca5b4cbc16a580cf5236097ec39e90e9
```

JSON structure is:

```
{
        "enabled": true,
        "services": [
                "933579ee8caafc4e818ddfe02ab58fdc"
        ],
        "tags": [
                "2a521880b86a0f043eb65cff37fac679",
                "b4fd044b9a7ab1146bb638ea42219b99"
        ],
        "bouquet": ""
}
```

The question is, what would be the best way to add new element to array "services" if the file contains "b4fd044b9a7ab1146bb638ea42219b99" value in the "tags" array. If this value does not exists in the "tags" array skip the file, else add "NEWVALUETOADD" to "services".

If "NEWVALUETOADD" already exists we can also skip the file.

Example output:

```
{
        "enabled": true,
        "services": [
                "NEWVALUETOADD"
                "933579ee8caafc4e818ddfe02ab58fdc"
        ],
        "tags": [
                "2a521880b86a0f043eb65cff37fac679",
                "b4fd044b9a7ab1146bb638ea42219b99"
        ],
        "bouquet": ""
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `if … then … else … end` might do:

```sh
jq --arg q "b4fd044b9a7ab1146bb638ea42219b99" --arg n "NEWVALUETOADD" '
  if IN(.tags[]; $q) and (IN(.services[]; $n) | not)
  then .services += [$n] else . end
'
```

```json
{
  "enabled": true,
  "services": [
    "933579ee8caafc4e818ddfe02ab58fdc",
    "NEWVALUETOADD"
  ],
  "tags": [
    "2a521880b86a0f043eb65cff37fac679",
    "b4fd044b9a7ab1146bb638ea42219b99"
  ],
  "bouquet": ""
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/B80tENcsem)

In order to then iterate over each file and modify it you need to use temporary files as jq does not have an in-place editing option (as `sed` does with `sed -i`).

```sh
for file in *
do jq --arg q "b4fd044b9a7ab1146bb638ea42219b99" --arg n "NEWVALUETOADD" '
    if IN(.tags[]; $q) and (IN(.services[]; $n) | not)
    then .services += [$n] else . end
  ' "$file" > "$file.new" && mv "$file.new" "$file"
done
```

Comment: One issue with this is that `jq` rewrites all files, regardless if these have been modified. You can use the `jq -e` with the `halt_error()` function or `false` to inform the shell, to skip the `&& mv "$file.new" "$file"`. Here: `jq -e --arg q "b4fd044b9a7ab1146bb638ea42219b99" --arg n "NEWVALUETOADD" 'if IN(.tags[]; $q) and (IN(.services[]; $n) | not) then .services += [$n] else false end' "$file" > "$file.new" && mv "$file.new" "$file"`

Comment: @LéaGris Good point. However, the temporary file(s) would nevertheless be created (then with just `false` as content), so adding something like `… || rm -f "$file.new"` would be advisable.

Comment: Use a standard temporary file in ram-disk with cleanup trap `unset tmpFile; trap 'rm -f "$tmpFile"' EXIT INT; tmpFile=$(mktemp) || exit 1; jq -e '.|.|.' "$file" > "$tmpFile" && cp "tmpFile" "$file"` or cache JSON data in a variable and write it only as replacement when needed  `json=$(jq -e '.|.|.' "$file") && printf '%s\n' "$json" >$file` .

Comment: Thanks for the code, it works, but there is a problem, as it turns out, the position of the new value is important. So `"services": [
    "933579ee8caafc4e818ddfe02ab58fdc",
    "NEWVALUETOADD"
  ]` is not good, it must be `"services": [ 
     "NEWVALUETOADD",
    "933579ee8caafc4e818ddfe02ab58fdc"
  ]`

Comment: Change the order by replacing `.services += [$n]` (which adds at the end) with `.services |= [$n] + .` (which adds at the beginning).

Answer (score 1):

This way:

```sh
jq --arg nv "NEWVALUETOADD" 'select(.tags[] | select(. == "b4fd044b9a7ab1146bb638ea42219b99") ).services += [$nv]'
```

The jq script:

```js
select(
  .tags[] | select(
    . == "b4fd044b9a7ab1146bb638ea42219b99"
  )
).services += [$nv]
```

[jqplay.org with this above](https://jqplay.org/s/Fsi0iM6c2O)

Comment: Congratulations for the [tag:bash] gold badge!

Answer (score 1):

One option would be using index in order to find exact match with the desired value and then add the new element such as

```
jq '(select(.tags | index("b4fd044b9a7ab1146bb638ea42219b99")).services )+=["New Value"]' yourfile
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/S2R8e2dcFO)</kbd>